# Вопрос по функции. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

```
nums = input().split()


def cmp(num):
    return sum([int(i) for i in num])
    

nums.sort(key=cmp)

print(*nums)
```

Функция принимает строку чисел и возвращает отсортированный список чисел в порядке неубывания суммы их цифр.

Что вызвало функцию в этой программе? Как передалось значение аргументу num? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Функция sort вызвала и передала что захотела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `sort` неявно вызвала функцию `cmp`, потому что эта функция указана в качестве ключа для сортировки списка.

> Как это работает?

Функции передали список на сортировку, но ей нужно знать по какому условию это делать, это необязательно по возрастанию или по убыванию, можно сделать это условие опциональным, как и в данном случае.

Происходит это следующим образом: "под капотом" вызывается функция `cmp` для каждого значения в списке, затем список сортируется по убыванию в соответствии с тем, какой результат возвратила функция для каждого элемента.

В данном случае в качестве ключа сортировки являлась сумма цифр в числе.